# Using Multi-threading for Slow Ms Interop

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, office-interop

I have a program that creates two pdf files when a button is clicked. It uses Microsoft office interop in WinForms and the file creation goes like this;

1. User works on something in the program
2. Clicks the button
3. Program creates a word file based on a template that has bookmarks in it
4. Writes into the bookmarks as well as its table
5. Saves it as pdf
6. Closes active documents
7. Closes the word app
8. Closes the child form and switches to another one

*the word app is not visible to the user

It works fine on its own, but then it takes up 8 seconds to complete the two files, so I tried using multi-threading so that the user won't have to wait and can work on other things or proceed to step 1 again.

However, it throws various errors; COM, RPC, etc. even in the database connection ones, and I think the reason is that since there are two separate threads that works and it uses the same resources, some point in time the other might have close the resources that the other thread is using / about to use
So I tried using join(), so that the other thread might finish its job first, close its respective resources, then proceeds to the next one.

This works fine, IF, the user does not click the button to create another file right after the other (in a scenario that the user finishes the first step faster than expected)

The `join()` is sufficient enough to handle the errors as well as to work on the file creations on background, however, I want to deal with the scenario when the file creation is done right after the other, because in this scenarios, it then seems like the process is linear due to the threads waiting for each other, aside from it creates bottlenecks wherein the threads are now in line and blocks the main thread, which makes the user wait for 12 seconds or more.

What I want to know / to be clarified in is that;

1. Can I create those two files that uses `interop` use different resources so that it won’t produce errors?
2. Can I use or is there an alternative to `join()` wherein it does not block the UI thread or the main thread? So that the file creating threads just line up in background (still waits for each other to finish) without making the user wait.
3. Did I incorrectly use join() or the threads that ends up eating more time?

Here is my code;

Procedure and public variables in a module for creating the documents:

```
Public tsThread As Thread
Public psThread As Thread

Sub SaveDoc(docType,someArgs)
        Dim wordApp = New Word.Application
        Dim templateBookmarks As Word.Bookmarks
        Dim templateName As String
        Dim template As New Word.Document
        wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        Select Case docType
            Case "Type1"
                templateName = "SampleType.docx"
                template = wordApp.Documents.Add(templatePath & templateName)
                templateBookmarks = template.Bookmarks

                templateBookmarks.Item("bookmarkInWord").Range.Text = "Foo"
                template.Tables(1).Cell(msWordRow, 1).Range.Text = "Value in cell 1"   
            Case "Type2"
                ‘Same thing, just different values and template
            Case "Type3"
        End select
        template.SaveAs2(savePath & saveName, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        wordApp.Quit()
End Sub
```

Procedure in the child form when the button is clicked:

```
        If Not IsNothing(tsThread) Then
            If tsThread.IsAlive Then
                tsThread.Join()
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(psThread) Then
            If psThread.IsAlive Then
                psThread.Join()
            End If
        End If
        tsThread = New Thread(Sub() SaveDoc(docType1,someArgs))
        tsThread.Start()

        If Not IsNothing(tsThread) Then
            If tsThread.IsAlive Then
                tsThread.Join()
            End If
        End If
        psThread = New Thread(Sub() SaveDoc(docType2,someArgs))
        psThread.Start()

        If records = maxRecords Then
            If psThread.IsAlive or tsThread.isAlive Then
                tsThread.Join()
                psThread.Join()
                Dim fooThread = New Thread(Sub() SaveDoc(docType3,someArgs))
                fooThread.Start()
            End If
        End If
   SwitchForm("Child Form for Step 1")
   End Sub
```

The errors i.e. without using the `join()` are commonly in these parts of code:

`wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)`

or in

`wordApp.Quit()`

Or in the bookmarks

`templateBookmarks.Item("bookmarkInWord").Range.Text = "Foo"`

Or sometimes anywhere inside one of the cases in different timings or in database connection procedures.

I am still relatively new to multi-threading as well as in Ms Interop so I seek help if I have any misconceptions. The code is in VB but I can understand C# as well. Any help / guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling both `wordApp = New Word.Application` and `wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`?

Answer (score 2):

1. I would not try to use any word/office interop from more than one thread at a time. In my experience these things are unreliable enough as it is, without introducing possible concurrency issues. But this might depend on what exactly you are doing.
2. Thread and join are rather old-school way to handle multiple threads. The newer method is to use [Tasks and async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/). This may help to enforce a consistent ordering, without blocking the main-thread.
3. You should typically avoid any method that can block when executing from the main thread, including .Join().

I would consider using producer/consumer pattern. The main thread would produce documents to process when the user clicks a button, while the background thread would consume the documents and do the processing. A [blocking collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) can typically be used as the interface between the two threads.

Another alternative is a [limited concurrency task scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1). This lets you schedule tasks to do the processing, while ensuring only one (or some other limit) are processed concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a macro enabled template with embedded VBA procedures that do all of the bookmarking and saving to PDF.  This reduces Interop calls to just creating/disposing the word application and running the VBA procedure with passed in parameters.